# Extracting json from ansible playbook

Tags: ansible

I am fairly new to Ansible, so apologies if this a naïve question.

When I execute Ansible Playbook using AnsibleRunner, I get output in the following format:

```
PLAY [MyPlay] ******************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [Gathering Facts] *********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [Get list of volumes] *****************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [debug] *******************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "volumes": {
        "Array_Software_Version": "2.0.0.0",
        "Cluster": [
            {
                "id": "0",
                "name": "111"
            }
        ],
        "Volumes": [
            {
                "id": "003ec9af-7a6d-473b-942f-3418da25d88c",
                "name": "server1"
            },
...
...
...
```

and my task

```
  tasks:
    - name: Get list of volumes
      task: execute
      register: volumes
      
    - debug:
       var: volumes
```

I'd like to extract just JSON payload, can I do this using Ansible?

Comment: What do you want to extract it from? 1) From the ``register: volumes`` or  2) from the [ansible-runner artifacts](https://ansible-runner.readthedocs.io/en/stable/intro.html#runner-artifacts-directory-hierarchy)?

Comment: ideally I would like to extract it from ansible script itself, but would like to see solution for ansible-runner as well.

Comment: If you want to get stdout of ansible in a script use *ansible-runner*. That's what *ansible-runner* is for (except for other things). Your playbook already writes the data to the stdout. You can find it in the *stdout* files of the [artifacts](https://ansible-runner.readthedocs.io/en/stable/intro.html#runner-artifacts-directory-hierarchy). In the (ansible) script run *ansible-runner* then read the *stdout* file. See [example](https://ansible-runner-role.readthedocs.io/en/latest/example3-status.html#wrapper-ansible-runner).

Comment: @VladimirBotka Thanks for suggestion. When I examine stdout, I get the whole output that is displayed in stdout. I have to do some extra work to extract the actual JSON payload. Is there way to retrieve the actual JSON payload from ansible run without resorting to reading and stdout and extracting the data?

Answer (score 0):

Q: **"*Retrieve the actual JSON payload from ansible.*"**

A: An option would be to use an intermediate file, for example

```yaml
shell> cat test-280.yml
- hosts: localhost
  become: true
  vars:
    volumes:
      Array_Software_Version: "2.0.0.0"
      Cluster:
        - id: 0
          name: 111
      Volumes:
        - id: 003ec9af-7a6d-473b-942f-3418da25d88c
          name: server1
  tasks:
    - copy:
        dest: /tmp/my_volumes.json
        content: |
          {{ {'volumes': volumes}|to_nice_json }}
```

```sh
shell> cat test-280.sh
#!/bin/bash
ansible-playbook test-280.yml > /dev/null
my_volumes=`cat /tmp/my_volumes.json`
echo $my_volumes
```

```yaml
shell> ./test-280.sh
{ "volumes": { "Array_Software_Version": "2.0.0.0", "Cluster": [ { "id": 0, "name": 111 } ], "Volumes": [ { "id": "003ec9af-7a6d-473b-942f-3418da25d88c", "name": "server1" } ] } }
```

Comment: Can you explain how vars works? In my payload I might have multiple Volumes elements, since it's an array. Will the script you cited capture that as well?